# how long does a company normally take to respond to the question asked for dissertation?

Tags: research-process, thesis, data

Because of the late decision to change my dissertation topic , I have a month to finish my dissertation.
For my research I have to contact some company(construction company, domestic and foreign )and wanted to know the time they normally take to reply so I can plan out the structure for my dissertation.

Comment: This can vary greatly.  Do you or your advisor routinely work with these companies?  That usually speeds things up but otherwise it could take days, weeks, or you could get no response.

Comment: You have a month to finish your dissertation and you don't even have a structure in place? Do i understand that right?

Comment: Have you heard the expression "How long is a piece of string?" This is basically that.  There's no way to know at this level of generality.  For that matter, if there isn't any good business reason for the company to work with you (will it lead to profits for them?), they might not reply at all.

Answer (score 2):

The time seems *extremely* short to me. Unless they know of the urgency and agree to expedite you could wind up without the data you need. A normal request could take a while as the person you contact needs, perhaps, to gather information from those who may be busy or unavailable.

They may be willing to work faster if prodded, but it might be better coming from your professor, if that is appropriate. A note that the information is needed asap to allow the completion of research might help if worded correctly. Unfortunately, people have their own priorities.

The more extensive the information, the longer it takes to pull it together, of course.

It sounds as if visiting the person you contacted, face to face, isn't an option here. But you may be able to use voice communication with your correspondents to get the data if it isn't too extensive. In that case, make appointments for calls.

I suggest that you don't wait for the information to come in before you start. There might be a lot you can do and only plug in the results in to a framework already in place in case the information is delayed. The structure of the dissertation shouldn't depend too much on the actual data, though the conclusions might.